# How to use a custom section handler without implementing the IConfigurationSectionHandler interface?

Tags: c#, configurationsection

I would like to create a section in my web.config file like this:

```
<paths>
                <path>\\123.123.132.123\c$\test\folder</path>
                <path>\\123.123.132.123\c$\test\folder</path>
</paths>
```

I am searching for alternatives, I would like to use one of the default section handlers, but I could only find section handlers that would work with this config

```
<CustomGroup>
        <add key="key1" value="value1"/>
</CustomGroup>
```

(that would be SingleTagSectionHandlers,  DictionarySectionHandlers, NameValueSectionHandler and so on).

Is there any way that I substitute the < add> tag for a < path> tag?
Or do I have to implement the IConfigurationSectionHandler interface?

Comment: I didn't find an alternative when I had to do this. But it's really not that difficult to implement.

Comment: Yes, it is not difficult, but I would rather not have this new class in the project, but I thinks this is the way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do I have to implement the IConfigurationSectionHandler interface?

You don't have to if you use the [System.Configuration.IgnoreSectionHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.ignoresectionhandler.aspx).

web.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="Paths" type="System.Configuration.IgnoreSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
  <Paths>
    <path>\\123.123.132.123\c$\test\folder</path>
    <path>\\123.123.132.123\c$\test\folder</path>
  </Paths>
```

Then you can manually read the web.config with whatever you want to get your values.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetPathsFromConfig()
{
  var xdoc = XDocument.Load(ConfigurationManager
    .OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
    .FilePath);

  var paths = xdoc.Descendants("Paths")
    .Descendants("path")
    .Select(x => x.Value);

  return paths
}
```

Other wise you'll have to [Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection (how-to)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I will create the custom config section then :) tks

Comment: @Oscar FYI you can't create section with elements containing text - configuration elements supposed to map properties to attributes. So, for your case it's better to ignore section and parse it manually.

Comment: You are right, just noticed that. I changed the layout for <path value=""> :) thanks for the info!